# Understanding how "vi" finds its global configuration file

Tags: vimrc, linux-ubuntu

On my Ubuntu OS, I see this in `/etc/vim/vimrc.tiny`:

```
$ cat /etc/vim/vimrc.tiny
" Vim configuration file, in effect when invoked as "vi".
```

Here's the partial output from `:version`:
`system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"`

It looks like the VIM environment variable is not defined - `echo $VIM` doesn't show anything.

So how does `vi` know to read `/etc/vim/vimrc.tiny`?

Comment: from within vim, check the output of `echo $VIM`

Comment: If `:echo $VIM` from within Vim prints `E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version`, try `:!echo $VIM`.

Comment: Then try e.g. `:e $VIM/vimrc` and use `<c-g>` to find its path. Alternatively, if `:shell` works, check there the value of `$VIM`

Comment: From the above methods, I found `$VIM` to be `/usr/share/vim`. So following the `:verson` output, I would think that the system vimrc file is `/usr/share/vim/vimrc`. However, `$ ll /usr/share/vim/vimrc` shows it's point to `/usr/share/vim/vimrc -> /etc/vim/vimrc`, not `/etc/vim/vimrc.tiny`, and there is no mention of `.tiny` in `/etc/vim/vimrc`. So it's not still unclear how the `.tiny` file is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a answer to your question, but a follow up on you comment:

> From the above methods, I found `$VIM` to be `/usr/share/vim`. So following
>    the `:version` output, I would think that the system `vimrc` file is
>    `/usr/share/vim/vimrc`. However, `$ ll /usr/share/vim/vimrc` shows it's
>    point to `/usr/share/vim/vimrc -> /etc/vim/vimrc`, not
>    `/etc/vim/vimrc.tiny`, and there is no mention of `.tiny` in
>    `/etc/vim/vimrc`. So it's not still unclear how the `.tiny` file is used.

---

You have `/etc/vim/vimrc` and `/etc/vim/vimrc.tiny`, because you installed multiple vim-related packages on Ubuntu.

- `/etc/vim/vimrc.tiny` is from the package "vim-tiny".
- `/etc/vim/vimrc` is from the package "vim-common"

In a default setup of Ubuntu only "vim-tiny" is installed. This is a small Vim build with limited features (e.g. no syntax highlighting). This package also created the file `/usr/share/vim/vimrc` as a symbolic link to `/etc/vim/vimrc.tiny`.

Later on a "bigger" Vim package was installed, like "gvim". This has a dependency on "vim-common". The package "vim-common" contains all the runtime files (syntax highlighting etc). This package also creates the file `/usr/share/vim/vimrc`, but this time as a symbolic link to `/etc/vim/vimrc`.

So: The file `/etc/vim/vimrc.tiny` is from the package "vim-tiny" and is not used anymore. The package is still installed and you can call the executable with

```
$ vim.tiny
```

To see all installed vim-related packages execute

```
$ dpkg -l \*vim\*
```

Comment: Ralf, thanks for sharing this. So you're saying when I invoke `vi`, `/etc/vim/vimrc` is read? I took a look at this file `/etc/vim/vimrc`, but it does not `set compatible`. So why is `vi` running in "compatible mode"? `/etc/vim/vimrc.tiny` does `set compatible`, which why I suspected the .tiny file is being used.

Comment: I explain why you have `vimrc.tiny` and `vimrc` in `/etc/vim`, as you asked in a comment. Which files are read can be displayed by executing `:scriptnames`.

Comment: BTW: `compatible` is the default. See `:help compatible`. When that help text mention `vimrc` , it talks about `$HOME/.vimrc` (or `$HOME/.vim/vimrc`).

Comment: `:scriptnames` is not available in this version. But you've answered my question. Thanks.

Comment: This answer was initially meant as a follow up on one of you comments. I updated it to make that clear.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at `:h VIMINIT` there is a list of places vim looks for a config, and it will use the first one found:

Most used are the user vimrc files:

> The user vimrc file(s):
>
> - "$HOME/.vimrc"         (for Unix and OS/2) (*)
> - "$HOME/.vim/vimrc"     (for Unix and OS/2) (*)
> - "s:.vimrc"             (for Amiga) (*)
> - "home:.vimrc"          (for Amiga) (*)
> - "home:vimfiles:vimrc"  (for Amiga) (*)
> - "$VIM/.vimrc"          (for OS/2 and Amiga) (*)
> - "$HOME/_vimrc"         (for MS-DOS and Win32) (*)
> - "$HOME/vimfiles/vimrc" (for MS-DOS and Win32) (*)
> - "$VIM/_vimrc"          (for MS-DOS and Win32) (*)

But there is also a backup and systemwide files. Have a look at the help since it is somewhat different depending on version,